# what is the equivalent of select() function (under winsock2.h) in WinRT(windows.networking.socket)?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winsock2

WinRT or Metro style doesnt support winsock2.h.
But my app use the selec() function of winsock2.h
I want to port my app to metro style.
Metro style use windows.networking.sockets for socket related purpose.
I need to know what is equivalent of **select()** in **windows.networking.sockets**

Answer (score 2):

You want the [Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226906.aspx) class.  The [ConnectionReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener.connectionreceived.aspx) event is triggered when a client connects.